# applying different color border to bottom of div

Tags: html, css, sass, border

I have a modal where the bottom 10% or so is a different color than the top, and am having trouble applying the border to the bottom, right now it appears as this

[image]

my goal is achieve this styling for the border here[image]

```css
.feature-pending {
  border: toRem(1px) solid $border-gray;
}

.feature-pending-footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: $primary-blue;
  min-height: toRem(61px);
  &__body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-pending">
  <h1 class="feature-pending__header">
    Attention!
  </h1>
  <p class="feature-pending__body">
    The Feature is pending generation of your Townify Home Keyword. If you are a new user please allow 1-2 business days from the day you created your account. if you are not a new user please <a class="feature-pending__contact-support" href="">
            contact support</a> for assistance.
  </p>

  <div class="feature-pending-footer">
    <p class="feature-pending-footer__body">Dismiss</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added sass - I assume that is what it is?

Comment: @mplungjan, yes you're correct, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.feature-pending {
  border-radius:3px;
}

.feature-pending-footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: $primary-blue;
  min-height: toRem(61px);
  *border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;*
  &__body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  }
}
<div class="feature-pending">
  <h1 class="feature-pending__header">
    Attention!
  </h1>
  <p class="feature-pending__body">
    The Feature is pending generation of your Townify Home Keyword. If you are a new user please allow 1-2 business days from the day you created your account. if you are not a new user please <a class="feature-pending__contact-support" href="">
            contact support</a> for assistance.
  </p>

  <div class="feature-pending-footer">
    <p class="feature-pending-footer__body">Dismiss</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think you can't solve this problem because of border , you need to delete

> border: toRem(1px) solid $border-gray

and add border-radius ,if it's need to you

Comment: Thank you, yes that works, now I just need convince the designer to take out the border in the mock! haha thank you!